# Finding $P(3≤X≤4\mid Y=2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a number chosen according to the discrete uniform distribution on the set $S$ of $10$ decimal digits ($0$ through $9$) and let $Y$ be a number chosen according to the discreet uniform distribution on $S$ with $X$ removed.

1. Determine and identify the conditional PMF of $Y$ given $X=x$.
2. Determine and identify the conditional PMF of $X$ given $Y=y$.
3. Find $P(3\le X\le4\mid Y=2)$

---

1. From what I know I have $P(X=x\mid Y=y)=1/10$.
2. And $P(Y=y \mid X=x)=\dfrac19$.
3. $$P(3\le X\le4\mid Y=2)={P(3\le X\le4 \cap Y=2)\over P(Y=2)}={\displaystyle \sum_{i=3}^4\frac1{10}\cdot\frac19 \over \dfrac19}=\frac15.$$

---

I am practically sure of everything except part 3. 
If I could get some tips It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $P(Y=2 \mid X = i) = 1/9$ is true for $i = 0,1, 3, 4, ... , 9$, but $P(Y=2) = 1/10$ overall.

Comment: I unfortunately disagree with all of your answers.  Remember that $X$ cannot equal $Y$.  I would have phrased $P(Y=y\mid X=x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{9}&\text{if}~y\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}~\text{and}~y\neq x\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ emphasizing that it is perfectly valid to have asked what the probability $P(Y=1\mid X=1)$ is.  You should find that $P(X=x\mid Y=y)$ should act very similarly... $P(X=1\mid Y=1)=0$ for example.

Comment: As for intuition, you should assume from the wording that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and as such if we look at our sample space as pairs $(x,y)$, we have all 90 possible pairs of unequal digits and each of these are equally likely to occur.  There are nine pairs with $2$ as the second element.

Comment: @JMoravitz  "let Y be a number chosen according to the discreet Uniform distribution on S with X removed"  Why would X be independent from Y? .

Comment: You're right, I misspoke.  My point still stands that each of the 90 possible pairs of unequal digits should be equally likely to occur.  It is like how when pulling two cards in sequence from a deck of cards without replacement, each pair of cards is equally likely to occur and how we can opt to pull the top two cards and look at the second card first rather than the first without affecting anything.

Comment: @RolfHoyer Why would you say that you have 10 choices for Y since the number of Y depends on the number X. I would definitely agree more with something of the line of $\sum_{i=1}^{x-1}(1 / 10)$. But I'am not really sure about it.

Comment: 1) Recognize that $P(X=1\mid Y=1)=0$ since it is stated that $Y$ cannot equal $X$.  2) Recognize that $X$ must be one of $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,9\}$.  3) Recognize that law of total probability implies $P(X=0\mid Y=1)+P(X=1\mid Y=1)+P(X=2\mid Y=1)+\dots+P(X=9\mid Y=1)=1$.  4) Recognize that since $P(X=1\mid Y=1)=0$ and due to the symmetry of the situation, that implies that each of these other terms must equal $\frac{1}{9}$.  5) Recognize that the exact same argument works if you were to have swapped $X$ and $Y$.  6) Finally, recognize that we can generalize to $P(X=x\mid Y=y)$ and $P(Y=y\mid X=x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answers 1 and 2 mixed up, and one not quite correct.   Answer 3 is way off.

1. The conditional PMF for $Y$ given $X=x$ is $\bbox[0.5ex]{\mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid X{=}x) = 1/9}$, though you should add that the support is $y\in S\setminus\{x\}$ for all $x\in S$.
2. The conditional PMF for $X$ given $Y=y$ is $\bbox[0.5ex]{\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}y)}$ but this is *not equal* to $1/10$.   As a hint, notice that the support will be $x\in S\setminus\{y\}$ for all $y\in S$, because when given that you will select $Y=y$ you cannot select $X=y$, but you may select from the other nine values without bias.
3. $\bbox[0.5ex]{\mathsf P(3{\leq}X{\leq}4\mid Y{=}2)=\mathsf P(X{=}3\mid Y{=}2)+\mathsf P(X{=}4\mid Y{=}2)}$.   There is no need to use Bayes' Rule if you *already* have the conditional PMF.